# How can I get Docker container output through a websocket?

Tags: docker, go, stdout

I am trying to send output from a docker container to the console using `fmt`, but when trying to do it i get this.

```
&{0xc0422a65c0 {0 0} false <nil> 0x6415a0 0x641540}
```

How do I do this? This is my full code.

```
func main() {
    imageName := "hidden/hidden"

ctx := context.Background()

cli, err := client.NewClient("tcp://0.0.0.0:0000", "v0.00", nil, nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Pulling \"" + imageName + "\"")
_, err = cli.ImagePull(ctx, imageName, types.ImagePullOptions{})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

containerConfig := &container.Config{
    Image: imageName,
    Cmd: []string{"./app/start.sh", "--no-wizard"},
}

resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, containerConfig, nil, nil, "")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

if err := cli.ContainerStart(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

timer := time.NewTimer(time.Minute)
go func() {
    <-timer.C
    if err := cli.ContainerStop(ctx, resp.ID, nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}()

out, err := cli.ContainerLogs(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerLogsOptions{ShowStdout: true, ShowStderr: true, Follow: true})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

io.Copy(os.Stdout, out) // This is what I want to change to print with "fmt".
}
```

Tried: (but does not display until container is done.)

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
buf.ReadFrom(out)
fmt.Println(buf.String())
```

**Intention:** Allow real-time console output to the web.

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do with `fmt`? If you want to stream the log output in "real time", you need to copy the stream to an `io.Writer`, just like you already are.

Comment: I do not want to do anything, I just want the data to come in and for me to have the ability to send the message through a websocket

Comment: Why does it need to be printed with `fmt`? You've already shown the correct way using `io.Copy`. I don't understand what goal here when you start by asking "how can I print the output with `fmt`?",  and then say "I do not want to do anything [with fmt]".

Comment: I just want to receive the output as it comes and send it using a websocket not to the console. What I have now just sends it to the console, but I want it going through a websocket. The first step is to get the output data as a string. (that is my issue)

Comment: I don't see any websocket code.  What have you tried so far?   How do you want to map the stream of bytes from the container to the websocket messages?  Do you want one line per message, or something else?

Comment: I want one line per message, I have not done the websocket stuff yet. My goal is to get the message to come across as a string. Kind of like this in node.js`
*.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data); 
});`

Comment: Read lines from the container and write to the websocket using conn.WriteMessage.

Comment: @CeriseLimón The issue is that I do not know how to get the logs line by line... I am quite new to Golang.

Comment: Use a [Scanner](https://godoc.org/bufio#Scanner) to read line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the answer to my question, I did some searching about scanners as Cerise Limón commented. Anyone else who seems to be having the issue that I did can use this code. Thanks to all that helped.

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(out)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}
```

Comment: `bufio.ScanLines` is the default, you don't need to set it.

Comment: Oh, i'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

`&{0xc0422a65c0 {0 0} false <nil> 0x6415a0 0x641540}` is not a bad output. This is a perfectly fine struct output. I think the the main problem is here just your lack of golang experience.

I'm a beginner as well and I can imagine that when you see an output like above you thought that "I made a mistake"

No you didn't. It's default `fmt` behavior when u try to print out a struct which contains pointers.

Checkout this instead of your `fmt.Println`:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", out)
```

Well this answer stands on my assumptions but if this is the case just ping me for more info.

Comment: This is what I got: `&{body:0xc0422b4580 mu:{state:0 sema:0} closed:false rerr:<nil> fn:0x641660 earlyCloseFn:0x641600}`